# Declaring a trait with 'where'

Tags: rust

I see a trait defined like this:

```rust
pub(crate) trait MyTrait
where  
    Self: serde::Serialize + for<'a> serde::Deserialize<'a>
{
}
```

What does it mean? And when to prefer this way?

Comment: `where …` means the same thing like everywhere else, it declares additional [trait bounds](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch10-02-traits.html#trait-bound-syntax) it means that the type (`Self` here) has to implement the traits listed after the `:`

Comment: @cafce25 Since OP is also saying "when to prefer this way", my interpretation is that OP is asking for `trait MyTrait: ...` vs `trait MyTrait where Self: ...`, of which there is _no_ difference. They do the same, i.e. `: Foo` is the same as `where Self: Foo`.     However, using `where` is more flexible as it allows any type, e.g. `trait Foo where Box<Self>: Bar` or `trait Foo where String: Foo`

Comment: As it stands, this question won't be here in 2 years time.